# Does uninstall of meteor remove .meteor directory items?

Tags: meteor

I started to get "the system cannot find the path specified" running meteor in a project directory thats been ok for months, reboot etc not resolving it.

So I uninstalled meteor via control panel (windows 10) downloaded latest version for meteor.com site and reinstalled.

back in project directory I then got error "your not in meteor project directory" a bit of SO tells me the .meteor/release number could be incorrect. When I look in the .meteor director everything has disappeared apart from the local directory.   This is the same in two separate project directories. It looks like the packages, releases ,version files etc have been removed - could or would the uninstall of meteor do this?

All seems a bit fragile....

Thanks

Comment: Uninstalling meteor shouldn't dig inside your project and delete stuff. Did you not put your .meteor folder in your git repository?

Comment: No I'm not using git these are just learning projects to test various ideas. So just stored in user directory. all created with meteor create in the past. I copied the missing from a backup. This gets passed 'not in a meteor directory error. I then get error that meteor-node-stubs needs installing. I can't understand how these specific files disappeared.

Comment: I have no idea why it's happening. Using git as a matter of course (even on POC projects) may seem overkill, but can save you. Lucky you had some backups anyway